# The management of files and folders in codeIgniter can be made from controller or model?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, controller, file-exists

I want to verify if file/folder exists on my CI system (not system folder), can i do it from controller or I need create a method on my model to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically a matter of choice. You can define your function in both your model and controller. But if you want to use it over and over from different controllers, then better define a new model and put that function in it. I'd define model which is to be used by many controllers that is having some common-general methods. Just to keep things apart and maintaining them later. Helpers are also a way to keep things separate.

Answer (score 0):

You have got many way for this :

- You can create an helper and put your function like `verify()`
- You can create a private function into your controller like

  ```
  private function _verify() { }
  ```

enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

Best to add this function in a codeigniter helper or in a library class(if you are fan of OOP). Load this automatically with autoload.php and call from wherever you need it.